# MySQLi Prepared Statement UPDATE affects 0 rows, silent fail with error checking

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have spent most of the day on this one, hopefully some of the more experienced folk out there might be able to throw me a hint.

**Setup**:

- A listing of form elements with a checkbox for each row - ie. select
  a gallery image from this list
- Each element is associated with an ID in the database, I am using the ID as the primary key for the table, an auto-incrementing integer
- The table (er_pics) has a column called 'visible' which is an integer (not boolean), so I can use different values to indicate a different type of visibility in the gallery for that image - also to simulate deletion from the gallery without actually destroying any data.

**Usage**:

- Check a box to select an image to perform one of three actions (currently):

  1. Hide - change 'visible' to 0
  2. Show - change 'visible' to 1
  3. Delete - change 'visible' to 5 (or anything other than 1 or 0)

I will be adding support later to select multiple images at a time, but for now I would just like to get this to work. Anyways, now that you have an idea of what I'd like to accomplish, let me show you some code.

---

**cpwin.php** - *this is displayed in a pop-up window*

```
if(isset($_POST['hideImg'])){
    if(isset($_POST['inP'])){
        if(!set_visible($mysqli, $_POST['inP'][0], 0)){
            echo("Error hiding image from gallery.");
        }
    }
}
```

**functions.php** - *secured file outside public_html*

```
function set_visible($mysqli, $id, $vis) {

    $visible = $vis + 0;
    $tID = $id + 0;

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE er_pics SET visible = ? WHERE ID = ?") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))) {

        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $visible, $tId) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $stmt->execute() or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

        // this outputs "VIS: 0, ID: 2 Affected Rows: 0"
        echo("VIS: " . $visible . ", ID: " . $tID . ", Affected Rows: " . $stmt->affected_rows);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

I could be completely off my rocker, but I use this same code to set/unset 'blocked' status for user accounts from the admin cp (same utility, same website, same database, different table)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdFFA.jpg) is a link to an image that I compiled from screenshots to help illustrate what I see, and if my explanation wasn't very clear.

I am simply not sure where else to look on this one, I've checked all of the answers that I could find related to this problem on a few relevant sites. I have added error reporting statements into the code at strategic spots, and made it spit me *something* out, even if I had to create an error there myself just to get that response. Everything seems to work fine, except that it is simply not updating the table. I'm about to WTFSmack this feature off my website here if I can't find something pretty quick.

Also I apologise if this question has already been answered, as I have spent hours searching for one, and have come up dry thus far.

Thanks to anyone who feels like trying to point me the right way here.

**[edit]**
I have a word saying 'visible' or 'hidden' sitting next to the image shown in the list to indicate that image's status in the live gallery; its value is dependent on the value in the 'visible' column in the database. When I tick a box, and click Hide, it should refresh the window with the current data, and indicate the image as 'hidden'. I do not get the expected behaviour, it simply says 0 rows affected, and the DB data doesn't change at all for me.

**[edit]**
Thanks to sectus, I think I realize how easily things like this can slip if you haven't set the error level up from the default. Apparently, $tId and $tID aren't the same, but you may not even know it if you're not on the ball. GG.

Comment: What is wrong? I see desired behavior but I cannot understand what is wrong. Screenshot - good, but could add more text explanation?

Comment: I have edited the question to answer your question :) I'm working on another feature of this control panel setup that is quite similar to the functionality I have explained above at the moment, so we'll see if I hit the same kind of issue, hopefully i'm just being a noob and forgetting a semicolon somewhere ;)

Comment: You should turn on all errors and find out that `$tID` and `$tId` is the different variables.

Comment: Sometimes I just gotta facepalm. Thanks man you rule :) idk how to accept a comment as an answer though ;)